# Core-Plot: Trouble Making Lines

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-plot

I've got an array of points for a standard line-graph like so:

```
Array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
               [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 10], [NSNumber numberWithInt: 20], nil],
               [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 30], [NSNumber numberWithInt: 40], nil],
               nil];
```

The points show up on the graph display fine, but I'm having trouble finding out how to connect these two points to form a line.  All the examples I can find online deal with plotting the paths of functions, such as f(x)=1/x.  I'm simply interested in connecting two points to display a line.

Thank you.

---

**EDIT 1**

Here is how I set up the graph:

```
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] init];
    CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTStocksTheme];
    [graph applyTheme:theme];
    graph.frame = self.view.bounds;
    graph.paddingRight = 4.0f;
    graph.paddingLeft = 4.0f;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.cornerRadius = 0.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *borderLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    borderLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    borderLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.01f;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = borderLineStyle;
    self.graphHost.hostedGraph = graph;
```

---

**EDIT 2**

To anyone with a similar problem, the solution you are looking for is the *dataLineStyle* property.

Comment: You didn't really post enough of your code to be helpful. But heres a tutorial you might want to follow: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application

Comment: You should include the code where you initialize the graph view and setup its properties. Core Plot does its own line drawing, its not something you should explicitly have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're talking about directly drawing lines in Quartz, something like this...

```
// get current context
CGContextRef ct = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextBeginPath(ct);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ct, startPointX, startPointY);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ct, endPointX, endPointY);
CGContextStrokePath(ct);
```

Without more info, I can't really help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I was hoping to do this via Core-Plot, though.  I've essentially got a basic graph set up, and these two points are plotted normally.  What I'm having a hard time figuring out is how to physically draw the line in Core-Plot.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry - I never use Core-Plot.  At least if you ever code it from scratch, you'll know how to draw a line!